# Poster image shows everywhere except in IE8

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, html5-video, mediaelement.js, poster

The mediaelement player works successfully in all browsers (and the poster image shows), except the poster image does not show in IE8 (just black). Here's my code:

```
<video id="video" poster="http://www.-domain-.com/img/testImage.jpg" preload="none" controls="controls" width="240" height="220" >
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.-domain-.com/video/testVideo.mp4"/>
 <object width="240" height="220" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.-domain-.com/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.-domain-.com/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
  <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=http://www.-domain-.com/video/testVideo.mp4" />
   <!-- Image as a last resort -->
   <img src="http://www.-domain-.com/img/testImage.jpg" width="240" height="220" title="No video playback capabilities" />
   </object>
   </video>
```

How can I get the poster image to appear in IE8? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support HTML5 video. The Flash fallback need to support it instead, or you need to make your own solution showing an image (when IE8 is detected, or rather, lack of html5 video support), then replace that with the Flash fallback when you want to play the video.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm aware that "IE8 does not support HTML5 video", but mediaElement claims "one file any browser", and it does play the video in IE8, it is just the poster image that I'm looking for help with. I don't know how to make my 'own solution', as you suggested. Any additional help will be welcomed.

Comment: I'm sure mediaElement can play the video by using Flash fallback in IE8, but poster image is a html5 video attribute so unless mediaElement support its own poster substitute specifically there won't be shown any poster image. The author of mediaElement need to support it in the future in that case. I would file this as a bug or feature request with him. Mocking a solution on top of this framework is not recommended as future behavior/compatibility with it is hard to predict.